# How to query all Revisions from TFS for specified work item's?

Tags: c#, tfs, wiql

Loading revisions like this is slow:

```
var revs = workItem.Revisions.ToList();
```

I want to get all revisions for all WorkItems, so I though about doing it through WIQL:

```
var flatQuery = new Query(store, "SELECT * FROM Revisions", workItemIds);
var revs = flatQuery.RunQuery();
```

But I don't know neither the name of available tables in TFS nor if it is possible at all.

Any suggestions to make those joins faster than one-by-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I don't know neither the name of available tables in TFS nor if it is possible at all.

Sure, we could use the following code to do that.

```
var collectionUri = $"http://{myserver}:808/tfs/{CollectionName}"
VssCredentials vssCredentials = new VssCredentials();
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), vssCredentials);
WorkItemTrackingHttpClientBase client = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
var revs = client.GetRevisionsAsync($"{projectName}", workitemId).Result;
```

For more demo code about TFS .Net library, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops#other-samples).